# How to make sure session are destroyed when browser is closed in zend

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework

I have an application developed in zend framework. The problem is that sessions are not destroyed when the browser window is closed. Any idea?

Comment: Did you close browser, not only window with page?

Comment: I closed the browser completely but when i reload the page sessions are still there, which i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onunload event to send an ajax request to your server that will destroy the session

See : [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload)

Comment: It seems that sessions are destroyed in chrome but not in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, sessions end when the user agent terminates, such as when an end user exits a web browser program. However, your application may provide the ability to extend user sessions beyond the lifetime of the client program through the use of persistent cookies.

If you don't use `Zend_Session::rememberMe()`, it should be destroyed after you close all windows of browser.

Comment: You could also check remember_me_seconds in application.ini.

Comment: Also take a look at         Zend_Session::forgetMe();

Answer (score 0):

The session variable wouldn't be destroyed until it expires or you clear the browser cookies.
You can see this same problem when we close the browser before logging out.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the session.cookie_lifetime to 0 in your php.ini or in your code.

```
The value 0 means "until the browser is closed."
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

code:

```
session_set_cookie_params (0);
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an API within Zend Framework that makes you able to trigger that setting as well?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.forgetme<br /> Zend_Seesion::forgetMe()

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I use Zend remember me option and I didn't find the solution but had a good idea, to store sessions using zend db handler and deletes older cookies by writing simple query to Delete expired sessions(if it cron task, that is a good solution).

For more information about zend session db handler you can find here,

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html